# Implementing thousands (1k = 1000, 1kk = 1000000) interpreter

Tags: php

**Problem**

I'm trying to create a tool that takes a number as input, for example - `1kk`, and replaces each `k` with multiplication by 1000, i.e. here we get `1000000`.

There's no problem when dealing with integers, but I'm struggling to implement and algorithm which will replace numbers with floating point like `12.345kk` with `12345000`.

---

**Possible solution**

Okay, I could replace each `k` with multiplication by 1000 and then `eval` the whole expression:

```
$inp= "12.345kk";
$number = preg_replace('/[kt]/','*1000',$inp);
eval("\$result = {$number};");
echo($result); // 12345000
```

but it's really **dangerous** since the tool takes user input, and user can write anything they want.

*Could you provide a safe solution to this problem?*

It's a PHP question, but I guess the solution should be more-or-less similar in other languages, an algorithm itself shouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php - count ocurances of K
and
`preg_match_all('!\d+\.?\d+!', $string ,$match);` multiply float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure about format of your number you can count `k` chars in your string, then cast it to number and multiply by proper power.

```
$inp= "12.345kk";

$count = substr_count($inp,'k');

$number = (double)$inp*1000**$count;

print($number);
```

Comment: Wow!! That's a really cool trick, absolutely amazing, thank you!

Comment: This must be the first time I see this functionality (non-numeric characters are ignored when type casting) used intentionally!

Comment: @vhu, @nicael but be careful and watch out for other locales. Not in every country `.` is delimiter for float number.

Comment: I, personally, would prefer either the regex version below or some other means of consistently parsing the string first. It's neat trick but wouldn't pass a code review.

Comment: I agree. Regex is more intuitive and everyone doesn't know about casting from string to numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to split the input into digits and multipliers and multiply the digits by `1000` to the length of the multiplier string:

```
$inp= "12.345kk";
$number = 0;
if (preg_match('/^([\d.]+)([kt]+)/', $inp, $matches)) {
    $number = $matches[1];
    $multipliers = $matches[2];
    $number *= 1000 ** strlen($multipliers);
}
echo $number;
```

Output:

```
12345000
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/4L8Ml)

Comment: Thank you, love you answer! Although I see an another one which is more simple

Comment: @nicael no worries at all - you should always accept the answer that best suits you.

Answer (score 1):

You're concerns are warranted, you should never run user input through `eval()`, unless you absolutely have to. You don't have to do that here. Let me show you one possible solution.

You can get the numeric part of the input by [casting it to `float`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). You can get the number of `k` characters by using [`substr_count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php). You can then calculate the resulting number by using the number of `k`s as exponent for the number `1000` and multiply that with the input number:

```
$inp = "12.345kk";

$number = (float) $inp;                        // 12.345
$factor = pow(1000, substr_count($inp, 'k'));  // 1000^2

$result = $number * $factor;                   // 12345000
```

Note that you could also use the [`**` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) instead of [`pow`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php). However, I'd argue that `pow` will be easily understood by programmers unfamiliar with PHP and is therefore preferable.

Comment: Clever trick, I'm accepting another answer since it comes earlier